# Angular ui router save to state name in service does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know if the "to state" is home state, i try to do this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function( event, toState) {
   // this function just save the state in the service
   // this.currentState = state
   PageService.saveToState(toState);
}
```

And from my nav controller:

```
// return PageService.currentState
console.log(PageService.getCurrentState()) // returns undefined
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure how you are saving and retrieving toState in PageService. However, if you want to get the state name, it's toState.name.

Comment: Hi, run your "stateChangeStart" in your app.run(), and get "toState.name" to detect if route is "home" or not. [if your didn't understand comment me]

Comment: This is what i did and i get undefined

Answer (score 0):

toState is basically an object. You must retrieve its value using dot operator. Like this:

```
 PageService.saveToState(toState.yourVariable)
```